# jqGrid jqGridImport jqGridExport

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

My task is to use functions jqGridImport and jqGridExport to save/load grid state.
Problem is jqGridImport does not give me expected effect.

1. I link the functions to grid's custom pager buttons.
2. I save (via POST) XML with config to a server. It's checked I have good XML files on server.
3. Then I load XML (from POST response) from the server and import it to grid. It's checked I get from response good XML.

How I tested:

1. load page with a grid
2. change sorting, hide some solumns, replace columns.
3. save layout
4. reload page to restore original layout
5. press "Load layout" button
6. have NO visible effect.

What do I miss?
Sorry for long rows.

second: I'm not sure if I will have good formed hgrid events handlers after gqGridExport/jqGridImport. Will they work correct? For example, will OnSelectRow work correct?

Thanks a lot for advance.

```
jQuery("#listU07").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager',{del:false,add:false,edit:false,search:false})
        .navButtonAdd("#pager", {caption: "Columns", buttonicon: "ui-icon-newwin", position: "last", onClickButton: function() {$("#listU07").jqGrid('columnChooser', {classname:"ui-jqgrid"});}})
        .navButtonAdd("#pager", {caption: "Save layout", buttonicon: "ui-icon-disk", position: "last", onClickButton: function() {$.post("u07savegrid", {xml: $("#listU07").jqGrid('jqGridExport', {})}, null, "json");}})
        .navButtonAdd("#pager", {caption: "Load layout", buttonicon: "ui-icon-folder-open", position: "last", onClickButton: function() {$.post("u07loadgrid", {}, null, "json").complete(function(data, status) {$("#listU07").jqGrid('jqGridImport', data); $("#listU07").jqGrid('remapColumns', {}, true);});}})
```

Comment: Well, what information should I add to get answer? Thanks